# If $f(1)=c$ and $f(x+1) = f(x) + f(1)$, then is $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$?

Tags: functions

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $c \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$ be fixed such that:

1. $f(1) = c$
2. $f(x+1) = f(x) + f(1)$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

I proved the following properties:

1. For any $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $$f(x + m) = f(x) + f(m) = f(x) + cm$$
2. $f$ is well-defined.

It seems that $f$ satisfy:

> For all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$

but I dont think its true, but if I can show that property, maybe $f(x) = cx$, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Maybe using $x = \lfloor x \rfloor - \text{frac}(x)$ will work, but it got me with this property:

> For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$: $$f(x) - f(\text{frac}(x)) = f(x - \text{frac}(x))$$

Any hints?

Thanks.

### EDIT

I noticed that $f$ is not injective. My bad.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\sin(2\pi x)+cx$.

Comment: Thank you, @JohnWaylandBales!

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, is that the unique solution?

Comment: No, let $f(x)=g(x)+cx$ where $g$ is periodic of period $1$.

Comment: I forgot to add "and $g(0)=0$."

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, why not "$g(m) = 0$, for all $m \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Well, if $g$ is periodic of period $1$, then that will follow.